# WCF Service hosted in a Windows Service - Wrong / Expected Namespace

Tags: c#, xml, wcf, serialization, datacontractserializer

I have a WCF Service that I've installed that keeps throwing an unexpected namespace exception upon startup. The odd part is that it works just fine if I host it via IIS or in visual studio via the WCFSvcHost. I'm unable to find any namespace declaration in the designer when setting up the installer ServiceHost. Any ideas?

I've had no issues serializing and deserializing the data when using the other hosts.

```
[DataContract(Name = "ClientSite", Namespace = "http://IAmRedacted.com/IAmRedacted.WCF.DataContract")]
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)]
public class ClientSite : IAppServerRequest
```

Exception:

> Service cannot be started. System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException:        Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. --->   System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Error in line 1 position 153. Expecting element 'ClientSite' from namespace 'http://IAmRedacted.com/IAmRedacted.WCF.DataContract'.. Encountered 'Element'  with name 'ClientSite', namespace 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/IAmRedacted.Framework.WCF'. at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.InternalReadObject(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, Boolean verifyObjectName, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver)
>      at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.ReadObjectHandleExceptions(XmlReaderDelegator reader, Boolean verifyObjectName, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver)
>      at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.ReadObject(XmlDictionaryReader reader, Boolean verifyObjectName)
>      at IAmRedacted.WCF.ClientSite.LoadClientSiteData()

'IAmRedacted.Framework.WCF' is an old namespace declaration that I used, but it's since been simplified and I'm unable to find a reference to it anywhere.

Comment: You have a class that _is_ a DataContract and _implements_ a ServiceContract at the same time? I am confused. Maybe some reflection tool is too.

Comment: Yes. That isn't standard? The client site provides all of the functionality. And it's a datacontract because I need it to persist to disk in the event of a failure.

Comment: It is unusual (to me at least). And it might very well be the cause of your problem. DataContracts should be simple message objects. Looks like you're (ab)using the tool to save a configuration. Post the top of IAppServerRequest with the ServiceContract, I think it matters.

Comment: @HenkHolterman

http://pastebin.com/vxpwD7TQ

I'll get rid of the ServiceContract/DataContract namespaces and retest.

It's a datacontract because I'm using the datacontractserializer rather than the generic xml serializer. I was having issues with merging xml items using the generic serializer.

Comment: Don't (just) get rid of the namespaces, split the class.

Comment: Its not a DataContract because its serialized data that's used in the service contract. I understand the purpose of using small lightweight datacontracts in your service implementation.  It's a datacontract because it's serialized and persisted to disk using the datacontractserializer. I guess I don't understand the point of splitting it.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I found the issue. When I had built this application awhile back I didn't realize that XML file generated would be saved in /syswow64 instead of the local directory (I'm new to creating services). It had old invalid XML schema which is where that franken namespace was coming from. Its all good now.

Comment: No, I don't do chat. If it works then OK, congrats. But I'm still skeptical about the design. You will need Separation of Concerns to scale up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't know that because I was using a Windows Service as a host, the XML file was saved to /windows rather than the local directory. The invalid namespace was from an old XML file that still existed in /windows/syswow64.